# Как передать данные из одного Activity в другое, а затем получить их изменёнными обратно?

Tags: android, kotlin, activity, android-intent

Нужно передать текст из MainActivity в EditPostActivity, где можно при желании отредактировать текст, затем вернуть этот отредактированный текст. Не могу придумать как передавать данные(post.content - одно из полей класса post) из viewModel.edited.observe(this).

Создаю контракт

```
 val editPostLauncher = registerForActivityResult(EditPostResultContract()) { result ->
            result ?: return@registerForActivityResult
            viewModel.changeContent(result)
            viewModel.save()
        }
```

Кнопка при которой должен измениться текст

```
viewModel.edited.observe(this) { post ->
            if (post.id == 0L) {
                return@observe
            }
            editPostLauncher.launch()
           }   
        }
```

Сам контракт

```
class EditPostResultContract(private val postContent: String) : ActivityResultContract<Unit, String?>() {

    override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Unit): Intent =
        Intent(context, EditPostActivity()::class.java)

    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): String? =
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            intent?.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)
        } else {
            null
          }
}
```

Активити где должен поменяться текст

```
class EditPostActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityEditPostBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.edit.requestFocus()
        binding.ok.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent()
            if (binding.edit.text.isNullOrBlank()) {
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, intent)
            } else {
                val content = binding.edit.text.toString()
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content)
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
            }
            finish()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял суть затруднений, то вам надо положить аргумент postContent в интент и в EditPostActivity его из интента достать. Соответственно, передавать postContent  в EditPostResultContract надо, вроде, через метод launch

Comment: Да, всё правильно. А не подскажите как именно через метод launch() передать post.content  сначала в EditPostResultContract? (с передачей аргумента из EditPostResultContract в EditPostActivity - проблем нет)

Comment: В вашем случае, вроде, просто вот так: `editPostLauncher.launch(post.content)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш контракт не принимает никаких входных параметров, ну почти. В текущей реализации вы прокидываете лишь параметр в конструктор и никак его в дальнейшем не используете.

**Как выйти из этого положения?** Модифицировать контракт следующим образом:

```
class EditPostResultContract() : ActivityResultContract<String, String?>() { // Допускаем, что входным значением будет тип `String`
    override fun createIntent(
        context: Context,
        input: String
    ) = Intent(context, EditPostActivity::class.java).apply {
        putExtra(LauncherActivity.SOME_KEY, input) // Пихаем значение 
    }

    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): String? {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return null
        return intent?.getStringExtra(LauncherActivity.SOME_KEY) // Достаем значение
    }
}

contract.launch("Your content goes here") // Запускаем  передав нужное значение
```

И не забудьте поменять ключ при отправке результата из другой активити.

З.Ы. Не совсем понимаю каким образом обсервинг чего-то должен запускать активити, может все же на кнопку какую забиндите?